# JavaScript's document.querySelector() same as jQuery $() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, document

I have been wondering why people glorified jQuery's `$(".myClass")` method when JavaScript has a generic `document.querySelector()`. Is there something I'm missing here? Why not just use the `document` object?

I am completely new to JavaScript, so is there some type of con to `document.querySelector()` that I am not aware of?

I'd really like to know, because I ran across something like this earlier and I'm wondering if it might help a situation I'm in:

```
var retrieve = function( s ) {
    return document.querySelector( s );
};

retrieve(".myClass").style.display = "block";
```

---

#### Note

I have nothing against jQuery at all. In fact, I love it. However, I'd rather not cheat myself using the easy pre-made ready-to-use tools when I'm just now trying to learn JavaScript.

Any help would be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Jquery supports more complex selectors, as well as it supports BC to the old browsers.

Comment: jQuery uses Sizzle as selector engine which provides all sorts of extensions to the "normal" CSS selectors. `document.querySelector()` is not supported in IE6 and IE7 (I think). Related (maybe): [John Resig - Thoughts on querySelectorAll](http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/).

Comment: Oh, so could I still do nested selectors like `document.querySelector("#myId .myNested .mySpan p")`? Or is that what you mean by "complex selectors"?

Comment: @ModernDesigner: how about `:eq(n)` and, say, `:parent`?

Comment: @Modern: Any CSS selector is supported by `querySelector` afaik and this is one. It's not a "nested" selector though, it's the descendant selector applied multiple times.

Comment: @zerkms, than what do you mean by "complex selectors"?

Comment: @ModernDesigner: I meant selectors that aren't part of specification, but which make life easier. `:selected` is another good example

Comment: From what I can see, `querySelector()` only returns the first match, whereas jQuery returns all elements it can match.

Comment: Oouch! Well that would be a deal breaker. Hehe.

Comment: @ModernDesigner: Well, some of the time yeah. :)

Comment: @bvukelic: That's why there's `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: So that would match all elements... ? :)

Comment: Yes, `querySelectorAll` will return a list of all elements that match the selector. The main downside of `querySelectorAll` (and `querySelector`) in my view is that it's not supported by older browsers.

Comment: What there is "non-constructive" of requesting finite number of differences of `.querySelector` vs. `$`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cross-browser and legacy support.

You can also use getElementsByClassName() if you don't want to use Jquery. There is a response to a [post on devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-get-all-elements-of-class-abc-24349.html) by user: KorRedDevil that may be of interest to you.

I took your function from your post and made it return an array. After you have that array of elements, all you have to do is loop over them. You can try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tEB6G/).

*Javascript*:

```
var retrieve = function(className) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
};

var elements = retrieve('foo');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.background = '#dfd';
```

*Markup*:

```
<p class="foo">foo</p>
<p class="bar">bar</p>
<p class="foo">foo</p>
<p class="foo">foo</p>
<p class="bar">bar</p>
<p class="bar">bar</p>
```

Comment: This question and answer reminds me of http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/. It wasn't there one year ago, but might be of interest to "future people".

Answer (score 15):

About a decade ago the top browsers were IE6, Netscape 8 and Firefox 1.5. Back in those days, there were few cross-browser ways to select an element from the DOM besides [**`Document.getElementById()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

So, when jQuery [**was released back in 2006**](http://ejohn.org/blog/barcampnyc-wrap-up/), it was pretty revolutionary. Back then, jQuery set the standard for how to easily select / change HTML elements and trigger events, because its flexibility and browser support were unprecedented.

Now, more than a decade later, a lot of features that made jQuery so popular have become included in the JavaScript standard. Instead of jQuery's [**`$selection.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can now use [**`EventTarget.addEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Instead of jQuery's [**`$()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), you can now now use [**`Document.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)... etc... which begs the question of why we should use jQuery at all. And indeed, people are increasingly [**wondering whether we should use jQuery at all**](http://www.sitepoint.com/do-you-really-need-jquery/). So, if you think you understand JavaScript well enough to do without jQuery, please do! Don't feel forced to use jQuery, just because so many others are doing it!

Anyway, to understand why jQuery is so popular, it's important to understand where we're coming from!

Comment: because jquery is in so many applications, and it is so concise, short and clear,  that you don't want to change all those code bases. If you're already working with JQ why replace it with clunky long js code?  And if you're writing another page why make that one different from all the others?

Comment: Most of the things people use jQuery for [can be replaced quite easily with vanilla JS](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). If that's too verbose for your taste, you can always write your own convenience wrappers or use focused libraries like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to do just those things you don't like writing your own code for. Does that mean you need to replace all the jQuery code in old websites? Of course not... but I sure as hell avoid jQuery in all of my new projects!